# What does "gets pulled" mean in a baseball game?

Tags: baseball, terminology

A guy is explaining some unwritten rules in baseball. At about [7'50″ into the video](https://youtu.be/0bKkGeROiPA?t=464), the guy says

> If a pitcher **gets pulled** they should stay in the dugout at least until the end of that inning.

What does "gets pulled" mean there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to remove the pitcher from the game mid-inning, typically because of ineffectiveness. So you normally don't use it for a specialist one hitter pitcher (pre-2020). See also "yank the pitcher".